# jsoup textarea format changing when writing out from Document.html()

Tags: html, textarea, jsoup

I am loading in a html document using the jsoup.parse().  I only want to modify the url references within the document and then write this out.  Unfortunately, the textarea within the document is getting modified also.  How can I write out the modified document with only my changes and no other changes?  Currently writing out the doc.html().

```
<textarea class="code_input" id="textareaCode" wrap="logical" rows="10" cols="50">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
</script>
</head>
</textarea>

<textarea class="code_input" id="textareaCode" wrap="logical" rows="10" cols="50">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;html&gt;
&lt;head&gt;
&lt;script&gt;
&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;/head&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;
</textarea>
```

Comment: Would you show us the code so far please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you mean. You want to unescape the html entities that are inside the `<textarea>` so that they are retained as proper tags.

Look into the `Parser.unescapeEntities()` function (see Jsoup [docs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html#unescapeEntities%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)).

Example using your sample html:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
String s = Parser.unescapeEntities(doc.html(), true);
System.out.println(s);
```

Will print out:

```
<textarea class="code_input" id="textareaCode" wrap="logical" rows="10" cols="50">
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <script>
   </script>
   </head>
</textarea>
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Bingo.  Just what I needed.